# How to install node-v6.11.0-linux-x86.tar.xz in Ubuntu

Tags: node.js, linux, ubuntu

I'm a windows user and I'm having a difficulty installing the latest version of [NodeJS](https://nodejs.org/en/download/).

I've tried `sudo apt-get install -y nodejs` and it installed  v0.10.25 version.

Can someone guide me how to install the tar.xz file properly.

Comment: Try https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-node-js-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: 2 clicks further on the same site: https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions

Answer (score 1):

Use [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm/blob/master/README.md)

It'll take care of everything.